# When making a tic tac toe game in javascript, how can you create an A.I. that will select any random box, but one that hasn't been chosen?

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, dom-events

I'm making a tic-tac-toe game, and I'm stuck. I sort of made an A.I. that moves after you but it's all a bit messed up. Try it yourself and see what happens. Can anybody have a look and see if they're able to improve it and explain how they did it? And to make things simple, how could I make the A.I. choose any box which hasn't been chosen yet.
Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="k1" value="  " onclick="tictactoe(this)">
    <input type="button" id="k2" value="  " onclick="tictactoe(this)">
    <input type="button" id="k3" value="  " onclick="tictactoe(this)">
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="k4" value="  " onclick="tictactoe(this)">
    <input type="button" id="k5" value="  " onclick="tictactoe(this)">
    <input type="button" id="k6" value="  " onclick="tictactoe(this)">
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="k7" value="  " onclick="tictactoe(this)">
    <input type="button" id="k8" value="  " onclick="tictactoe(this)">
    <input type="button" id="k9" value="  " onclick="tictactoe(this)">
    <script>
        var Xturn = true;
        var nummoves = 0;
        var cat;
        function tictactoe(square) {
            var value = square.value;
            var doc1 = document.getElementById("k1").value;
            var doc2 = document.getElementById("k2").value;
            var doc3 = document.getElementById("k3").value;
            var doc4 = document.getElementById("k4").value;
            var doc5 = document.getElementById("k5").value;
            var doc6 = document.getElementById("k6").value;
            var doc7 = document.getElementById("k7").value;
            var doc8 = document.getElementById("k8").value;
            var doc9 = document.getElementById("k9").value;

            for (nummoves = 0; nummoves < 2; nummoves++) {

                if (doc1 == "X") {
                    cat = document.getElementById("k2").value = "O";
                    Xturn = true;
                }

                if (doc2 = "X") {
                    cat = document.getElementById("k4").value = "O";
                    Xturn = true;
                }

                if (doc3 == "X") {
                    cat = document.getElementById("k5").value = "O";
                    Xturn = true;
                }

                if (doc4 == "X") {
                    car = document.getElementById("k9").value = "O";
                }
            }

            for (nummoves = 2; nummoves < 3; nummoves++) {

                if (doc1 == "X") {
                    cat = document.getElementById("k7").value = "O";
                    Xturn = true;
                }

            }

            if (value != "X" && value != "O") {
                if (Xturn == true) {
                    square.value = "X";
                    return Xturn = false;
                    nummoves++;
                } else if (Xturn == false) {
                    square.value = "O";
                    return Xturn = true;
                    nummoves++;
                }
            } else {
                alert("That square has been clicked.");
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note the whole concept isn't mine I admit, but i did kind of it the A.O. part which is slightly messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of a list of open squares, and just randomly select from that list.

That way you can eliminate the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate thought the "buttons" and take the first that is not checked, or another one, based on random.

```
for(i=1;i<10;i++) {
   if (document.getElementById('k'+i).value = ' ') {
       // not played yet !
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following logic:

```
// function that does an AI move
function doAIMove(xOrO) {
    // randomly gets a number from 1 to 9
    var randomSquare = document.getElementById("k" + getRandomInt(1, 9));
    while (randomSquare.value != " ") {
        randomSquare = document.getElementById("k" + getRandomInt(1, 9));
    }

    randomSquare.value(xOrO);
}


function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

That is not efficient, but it works as you asked. Anyway, you need to check if there's still remaining squares to fill in.

You should also consider implementing "the" tic tac toe AI, which is very simple. You should follow this pseudo algorithm for so:

When making a tic-tac-like game, the AI should work like this:

```
1. Check if there is a tile that you can win in 1 move
    if there is no such tile:
2. Check if there is a tile that your opponent can win in 1 move
    if there is no such tile:
3. Check if there is a tile that can make two tiles apply to the rule #1
    if there is no such tile:
4. Check if there is a tile that your opponent can make two tiles apply to the rule #2
    if there is no such tile:
5. implement your own AI form this point
```

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhatkrishnakishor/LGHHQ/) link for the HTML and JS/JQuery implementation for Tic-Tac-Toe. 
Currently its only a two player implementation without computer as opponent. Hope you can build on top of it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo by bhatkrishnakishor</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>



  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type='text/css'>
    .tictactoe {
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    background: #A2A8A1;
};
  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
//this is a demo tic tac toe game
$(document).ready($('input.tictactoe').click(tictactoe));
$(document).ready($('#ff').click(reset));

var whoseMove = 'X';
var xMove = new Array();
var oMove = new Array();
var gameOver = false;
var winningConditions = new Array(     'aa/ab/ac','ba/bb/bc','ca/cb/cc','aa/ba/ca','ab/bb/cb','ac/bc/cc','aa/bb/cc','ac/bb/ca');
var whoWon = '';

function tictactoe() {
    if(gameOver == false && this.value == '  '){
        if(whoseMove == 'X'){
            this.value = whoseMove;
            xMove[xMove.length] = this.id;
            whoseMove = 'O';
        }
        else {
            this.value = whoseMove;
            oMove[oMove.length] = this.id;
            whoseMove = 'X';
        }
    }


    if(xMove.length >2){
        whoWon = endGame();
    }

    if(gameOver && whoWon != '' && whoWon != 'draw') {
        alert(whoWon + ' won!')
    }

    if(!gameOver && whoWon == 'draw') {
        alert('Games been draw!');
    }    
}

function endGame() {
    var winningCombinations = new Array();

    //set this variable value to true incase the game is over
    gameOver = true;    

    for(var index = 0; index < 8; index = index + 1){
        var xMatchCount = 0;
        var oMatchCount = 0;
        winningCombinations = winningConditions[index].split('/');
        for(var i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 1){
        console.log('winningCombinations ' + winningCombinations[i]);
        for(var j = 0; j < xMove.length; j = j + 1){
            console.log('xMove ' + xMove[j]);
            if(winningCombinations[i] == xMove[j]){
                xMatchCount = xMatchCount + 1;
                if(xMatchCount == 3){
                    return 'X';
                }
            }
        }
        for(var k = 0; k < oMove.length; k = k + 1){
            //console.log('oMove ' + oMove[k]);
            if(winningCombinations[i] == oMove[k]){
                oMatchCount = oMatchCount + 1;
                if(oMatchCount == 3){
                    return 'O';
                }
            }                
                }
        }
    }

    console.log('x Move Count ' + xMove.length);
    console.log('o Move Count ' + oMove.length);

    if(xMatchCount < 3 && oMatchCount < 3){
        gameOver = false;
    } 

    if(xMove.length + oMove.length == 9){
        return 'draw';
    }
}

function reset() {

    console.log('Xs Move - ' + xMove.join('/'));
    console.log('Os Move - ' + oMove.join('/'));
    console.log(winningConditions.length);

    whoseMove = 'X';
    xMove = new Array();
    oMove = new Array();
    gameOver = false;
    whoWon = '';

    $('input').filter(function() {
    if(this.id != 'ff') {
        this.value = '  ';
        }
    });
}
});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
      <input type="button" id="aa" class="tictactoe" value="  ">
    <input type="button" id="ab" class="tictactoe" value="  ">
    <input type="button" id="ac" class="tictactoe" value="  ">
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="ba" class="tictactoe" value="  ">
    <input type="button" id="bb" class="tictactoe" value="  ">
    <input type="button" id="bc" class="tictactoe" value="  ">
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="ca" class="tictactoe" value="  ">
    <input type="button" id="cb" class="tictactoe" value="  ">
    <input type="button" id="cc" class="tictactoe" value="  ">
    <br /><br />
    <input type="button" id="ff" value="Reset">

</body>
```